# Calling multiprocessing pool on an instance method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've a Driver class which has an instance method write. I'm trying to use Python multiprocessing to apply this instance method on objects in queue.
Here's my code.

class Driver:

```
def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
   #initialize

def write(self, key):
    # do something
```

Here's how I'm calling it on a collection.

```
def write_to_db(key, d=Driver(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None)):
    d.write(key)

def main():
  .........
   with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
                    driver = Driver(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3)
                    _ = pool.map(write_to_db, (arr, driver))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

How can I get this right?

Comment: can you please show more of your code? I'm missing for example the important `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause and if I see it right, your `main()`-function is outside of the class `Driver` ,right?

Comment: In your `pool.map`, `write_to_db` will only be run twice, once with `arr` as the argument, and once with `driver`. Is that really what you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't, if you have shared state the object won't be picklable and python will throw an error.
The long answer, to do this, you have to instantiate the object inside a process in the pool.

You can instantiate the pool in this way,

```
  with mp.Pool(processes=processes, initializer=_worker_init, initargs=(config,)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(_worker_apply, resources)
```

`config` passes if you want to pass configurations
`resources` is the collection here on which the individual processes will work.

```
    def _worker_init(config):
        # initialize the object here


    def _worker_apply(payload):
        process = mp.current_process()
        return process.simulator.apply(payload)# implement the apply function to manage state of the object
```

Hope this helps.